# Getting ArcGIS for SharePoint up and running?

Tags: installation, esri-maps-sharepoint

I am having some issues getting ArcGIS for sharepoint up and running.  I'm not overly fluent with sharepoint, but I don't know what's going on.  I have it installed on my sharepoint along with ESRI maps for sharepoint, and I cannot get either to load when I add them to the site.  At first, the ArcGIS had a map background show up, but now the box shows up with nothing in it.  I can edit the actual properties that pop up, but I cannot use any of the edits on the top of the screen such as add data, change basemap, or anything really.  Not sure if something happened but hoping someone can assist.